# nginx not starting: unsupported Verneed record of libGeoIP.so.1

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, libraries

I have been running nginx on my Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS server for more than one year without problems.
However, since a few days nginx fails to load (access.log shows last connection from June, 13th 2016).
The output of nginx -t shows the following error:

```
nginx: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGeoIP.so.1: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record
```

I do not recall making any changes to the system. However, I have UnattendedUpgrades enabled. Removing and reinstalling nginx (apt-get remove nginx) does not fix the problem either. Does anyone know how I could go on with debugging?

Comment: Where does this nginx comes from?

Comment: I installed nginx using apt. Nothing I compiled. Also, I double-checked if I changed anything on June, 13th. I am positive that I did not touch anything around that time.

Comment: Show versions of `nginx` and `libgeoip1` packages.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. libgeoip is version 1.6.0 and apt shows that nginx is on version 1.4.6. Any ideas what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Not sure. Try to reinstall libgeoip1

Comment: I feel stupid. As suggested by Alexey Ten, simply removing and reinstalling libgeoip1 using apt did the trick. Now everything is running smoothly and as it should. However, I have no idea what caused these problems. Thank you very much for your help!!